# Unable to serialize Azure ServiceBus Message - Error getting value from 'ExpiresAtUtc'

Tags: c#, json.net, azureservicebus

I need to write a test where I manually create a Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Message and serialize it to JSON.  Example code:

```
    var message = new Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Message
    {
        MessageId = "0c8dfad9-6f0f-4d7f-a248-2a48fc899486",
        CorrelationId = "78b507b0-6266-458d-afe6-7882c935e481",
        Body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello world"),
    };

    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message);
```

However, I get the following exception when serializing:

```
    Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException : 
Error getting value from 'ExpiresAtUtc' on 'Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Message'.
    ---- System.InvalidOperationException : Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
```

Any ideas how I can create a valid Message (that can be later serialized)?  ExpiresAtUtc is get only so cannot be directly set. Is there a way to indirectly set it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ExpiresAtUtc` is set by the broker, considered an internal (`SystemProperties` collection), and is intentionally designed that way. There was a [similar question](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/issues/114) about testing and if you really need this, the only way to achieve it would be using reflection.

```
var message = new Message();
//message.TimeToLive = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
var systemProperties = new Message.SystemPropertiesCollection();

// systemProperties.EnqueuedTimeUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(1);
var bindings = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.SetProperty;
var value = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(1);
systemProperties.GetType().InvokeMember("EnqueuedTimeUtc", bindings, Type.DefaultBinder, systemProperties, new object[] { value});
// workaround "ThrowIfNotReceived" by setting "SequenceNumber" value
systemProperties.GetType().InvokeMember("SequenceNumber", bindings, Type.DefaultBinder, systemProperties, new object[] { 1 });

// message.systemProperties = systemProperties;
bindings = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.SetProperty;
message.GetType().InvokeMember("SystemProperties", bindings,Type.DefaultBinder, message, new object[] { systemProperties });
```

**Note** that approach is not coming from Azure Service Bus team as they see it a dangerous practice that could end up in your production.

Comment: Was hoping there might be a more elegant way of setting the message up without using reflection but if there isnt then fair enough :-)

Comment: In a way Clemens is correct by saying things can get out of control. It's a delicate balance.

Comment: I am encounter the same issue here in 2019, was trying to use Message as our base class for all messages, but failed to deserialize due to the ExpireAtUtc property, is there any better way to handle this scenario?

Comment: It's the same `Message` as it was in 2018 